# BIOSCOM command in c programming

Tags: c, c++builder

I've been assigned a project in which I've to basically read the
information from an interface eg:hardware interface like the device
through which employees have to swipe their i.d card when they enter
the office...and then through the c program written by us, this data
has to be sent to the internet spread sheet of a perticular person
eg:in this case the boss...
I came to know that this information comes to the computer through the com port.
but I wanted to know commands in c which will recieve data from com port..
and also how to access the spreadsheet of the internet thru c commands...

I thought that the 2nd part i.e sending info to spreadsheet can be
sent by considering the spreadsheet as a file.... is it possible? If
yes how?

I tried few programs that I found in internet, though I have
BIOS.h header file, it's showing no reference to BIOSCOM command. What
do I do? I'm working with borland compiler in windows32.

Answer (score 1):

I just left a job where I was using Borland C++ Builder 5 for 4.5 years. I don't know what version of Borland you are using, but since you mentioned Win32, you can use [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a [DCB Comm structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read data from the COM port. This website on [Serial Communication with Borland C++ Builder](http://maikel.galeon.com/serie/bcbcomm.html) will help show you how to do that in a simple example.

As far as writing data to a spreadsheet, well that seems a little rudmentary as far as a database goes, but you can interact with Microsoft Office through a COM interface. You could write a COM DLL using Visual Studio .NET and then make your functions COM visible so older compilers (such as Borland C++ Builder 5) can utilize .NET functions. This would probably be easier than trying to implement a COM interop directly in Borland C++ Builder.